# How do they extract kernels from sunflower seeds in mass production?

Tags: seeds, flowers, food-processing, extracts

[image: Sunflower Seeds and Seed Kernels]

Every time I seed a gunny sack of sunflower seed kernels in a supermarket, I wonder how they are extracted from their seeds. It is very difficult to extract even one of them by hand without smashing its kernels, I really wonder the process that extracts mass of them.

How do they do it? Is there a documentary or Youtube video about it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By using a dehuller machine. See:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hegzzj9Rzk
or
http://www.buhlergroup.com/global/en/products/dehuller-dgba.htm

How does a dehuller work? I don't know, but it seems that Google does:

> The most popular decorticator for sunflower is proposed by the Bühler
>   Cie. It consists in a rotating blade that propels the seeds by
>   centrifuge force against a wall. It functions on one impact. It is
>   designed for partial removal of hulls because due to its principle, it
>   is not able to carry out a good dehulling without increasing the force
>   of the impact. The kernel oil content is so high in sunflower that
>   under the violence of he chock, some oil can be transferred to the
>   hulls and is lost. Moreover, increasing the rotating speed of such
>   dehuller drives to increase the production of fines that are difficult
>   to separates from hulls. Another mono-chock kind of dehuller is
>   air-jet impact where the propelling of the seeds is done by a strong
>   current of air. Multi-chocks dehullers like the Ripple mill improve
>   the dehulling quality because they carry out several impacts on the
>   achene with milder violence and enable en enhanced separation of hulls
>   without generating an excess of fines.

See: http://www.creol.fr/CTMSite/creol/us/travaux/img/dehulling_3.pdf

See also: http://www.buhlergroup.com/northamerica/downloads/DGBA_Sunflower_Dehuller.pdf for some schematics of the inside of the machine and some insights about the way it works.

Comment: It is good to know that this machine exists, but a good answer would give a brief explanation of how it actually works.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to post this description here. By the way, you can edit your own answers, posting new information as a different answer is confusing. This time, I added it to your original answer for you. And also gave you an upvote because now the answer is quite good.

Answer (score 3):

Just to visualize a bit Raco's answer. There is a scheme of the Buhler machine provided by Buhler Group.

[image]

In the brochure from [here](https://www.buhlergroup.com/content/buhlergroup/global/en/products/sunflower_impactdehuller.html) (but not well explained).

Also, oilseed processing machine looks similar: https://www.buhlergroup.com/content/buhlergroup/global/en/industries/Oilseed.html

*This is not an answer actually, just a few more links to investigate the topic.*